# Select rows where one column has duplicate values based on another column which contains specific strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where in customer number column contains duplicate values and I would like to select all rows where there are duplicate entries for customer number, but only select those rows where WO Type column only contains these specific values ('IMU','Electric') so in the table image attached to this question: I should only get rows for ID 1 and 2.

I do not want those duplicates counted where the pair of duplicate rows also contain GAS, but only want those duplicate rows which exclusively contain only IMU and Electric values in WO Type Column

Your help is much appreciated.

[image: Customer Table]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select customerNumber
from t
where woType in ('EMU', 'Electric')
group by customerNumber
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes no duplicates.  To handle this, you can use:

```
having min(woType) <> max(woType)
```

or:

```
having count(distinct woType) = 2   -- number of elements in IN list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl t2 
    WHERE t2.customernumber = t1.customernumber 
        AND t2.wotype = 'IMU'
) AND EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl t2 
    WHERE t2.customernumber = t1.customernumber 
        AND t2.wotype = 'Electric'
) AND NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM tbl t2 
    WHERE t2.customernumber = t1.customernumber 
        AND t2.wotype NOT IN ('IMU', 'Electric')
)
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30c0a/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select * from Table1 Main
Inner JOIN (
select Customer_Number
From Table1 
group by Customer_Number
Having COunt(Customer_Number)>1) SUB ON Main.Customer_Number=SUB.Customer_Number
WHERE Main.Wo_Type IN ('IMU','Electric')

This Query will return the duplicate set or rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you this works but it also counts those rows where there is a 3rd WOType which I do not want. But thanks for the help though